# How can I keep a MPMoviePlayerController from dismissing on lock button press?

Tags: video, locking, mpmovieplayercontroller, background-process

I am attempting to play the sound from a video while the iphone screen is locked.  Can I keep the MPMoviePlayerController from being dismissed by a lock screen press?  If not I plan to subclass a MPMoviePlayerController and prevent it from being dismissed by a lock button press, which method will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After toying with a thousand other things I found what I needed to do.

All I needed to do was make two adjustments:

1. Add this to the AppDelegate.m in the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

   ```
   NSError *error = nil;

   BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
               setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
               error: &error];

   if (success == false) { /* handle error */ }
   ```
2. Add the following to your info.plist after you drag it into a text editor like Sublime:

   ```
   <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
   <array>
           <string>audio</string>
   </array>
   ```

If you setup your video correctly you will be able to listen to the audio from the video while using other apps and while the screen is in sleep mode.

Comment: I went to add this code to my app only to realize I had already put it there some time ago. I suspect this may have worked in previous versions but it's not working for me now (iOS8)